# A problem related to the factors of $(2^n+1)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Here's the conjecture:

> For $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, $(2^n+1)$ always has a **prime** factor with form $(2nk+1)$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}^*$, with an exception when $n=3$.

For example, when $n=5$, we have $2^5+1=33=3\times 11$, here the factor $11$ can be written as $2\times 5\times 1+1$, which means $k=1$ satisfies the conjecture.

I've verified this conjecture for $n\le 100$ but can't come up with an idea to prove or disprove it. I noticed that Zsigmondy's Theorem has a similar form but I can't find a good way to apply it in this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem) is what you nedd.

Comment: With $a=2$ and $b=1$ you have the desired statement. "primitive" means that the order is maximal ($2n$) for some prime factor and hence this prime factor must be congruent to $1$ modulo $2n$.

Comment: Fermat primes appear to be an exception to your conjecture.

Comment: @ordptt 65537 itself is the desired prime factor since 65537=2*16*2048+1

Comment: I see. Well, then at least it is easy to check that the conjecture holds for every fermat prime.

Comment: @Peter Why do you say "'primitive' means that the order is maximal (2n) for some prime factor"? I can't quite see the relation here, though the later part is ok for me. Could give some detailed explanation on this? Thank you so much!

Comment: I meant : There is a primitive prime factor (which means that it has maximum order). Maybe , this was formulated confusing.

Comment: I have found the following OEIS entry that is related to this question:
https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C5%2C17%2C11%2C13%2C43%2C257%2C19%2C41&sort=&language=english&go=Search

It does not provide a proof; however, this is a strong evidence that the conjecture is true.

Answer (score 1):

By Zsigmondy's theorem there is an odd prime $p$ which divides $2^n+1$ but does not divide any number of the form $2^k+1$ for $k< n$. We have $2^n\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, so $2^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. If you manage to prove that $2n$ is exactly the order of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^*$ you are done, since the order of an element has to divide the order of the group, and $2n\mid (p-1)$ is equivalent to $p=2nk+1$. Essentially you just have to prove that $2^d\not\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ for any divisor $d$ of $2n$.

Comment: Actually you don't have to proof that the other is exactly $2n$ since we already have $2^{2n}=1\pmod p$ and if we prove that $2n<p$ then it's enough to say that $2n$ is a factor of $\varphi(p)=p−1$.