# Is $7$ the greatest prime factor of some $2^n+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I'm looking for theorems that say something about relations of factors between consecutive numbers. In this case relations between greatest primefactors of consecutive numbers. I've tested for $n<10,000$ but find no $n$ such that $7$ is the greatest prime factor of $2^n+1$.

I've found out that given two different primes $p,q$ there is always a natural number $n$ such that $p|n$ and $q|n+1$.

> So I would like to find a number $n$ so that $7$ is the greatest prime
> factor of $2^n+1$ or a proof that there is no such $n$.

Comment: Congruence modulo seven does not solve this problem completely?

Comment: @SMC - So I have to learn more about modulo calcules.

Comment: If you are interested in this kind of argument i will suggest it yes.

Comment: Hint: First look for an exponent $n$ such that $7\mid 2^n+1$.

Comment: I suggest you calculate the remainders mod 7 of $2^1$,$2 ^2$, $2^3$,$2^4$. etc., multiplying by 2 to get each one from the one before. Spot the pattern.

Comment: For a "standard" proof of the $p\mid n$, $q\mid n+1$ question I recommend that you familiarize yourself with [the Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). It really settles many elementary number theory questions.

Comment: This can be deduced by Størmer’s theorem, applied to the set $\{2,3,5,7\}$.  Baker’s theorem also gives an effective bound for how far you have to look before there are no more solutions guaranteed.

Comment: $\dfrac{2^{3n}-1}{2^3-1}$ is an integer. This could help maybe.

Comment: The answer and the comments will certainly help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jykri Lahtonen says, the most natural thing to do is to look at
the congruence
$2^n\equiv -1\pmod{7}$.

If you know a bit more about elementary number theory and know things like Fermat's little theorem, primitive generator of $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ or quadratic residues/nonresidues, you can probably interpret the following problem in a more enlightening perspective.

But assuming you don't, you can observe that $2^n$ is only ever $2, 4$ or $1\pmod{7}$ just by listing out the first few exponents. That should tell you what are the possible values of $2^n+1\pmod{7}$ and conclude no such $n$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

It can be proved using [Zsigmondy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem) that given any $n$, the number $2^n+1$ has a prime factor of the form $2nk+1$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$. So, for your question, you only need to check the cases $n=1,2,3$ by hand. You can find the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4231477/943723).

This completes the proof I guess.

Comment: Can anybody explain the reason for the downvote? Anything wrong with the answer?

Comment: I think, the only reason for the downvotes (and the later deletion) is that there is a much easier solution, namely that $7\mid 2^n+1$ is not possible at all. The method is therfore an overkill, but the answer nevertheless absolutely correct.

Comment: @Peter Yes, later when I saw the other answers, I understood that mine was an overkill. So, I agree with you on that. But, can you tell me a different thing... I am quite new to this site and I often don't understand its activities properly. From your comment, I guess my answer was deleted, but how did it come into existance again? As far as I remember, I saw a few downvotes on the day I posted it, and today suddenly, I'm again recieving activities on this post. I don't understand how it happened :(

Comment: The answer was undeleted and has now 2 upvotes. It seems this was not in your interest, but I thought an undeletion (and a later upvote) would make you happy. You can delete the answer , if you do not want its "revival". The theorem has its merit in similar situations, so I think the undeletion was justified.

Comment: @Peter no no, it's absolutely fine. In fact, I thank you for the undeleting it. I was just a little confused about how this site works. Now, I understand. So, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on daruma's answer,

First observe that any number is in one of the forms: $3n,3n+1$ or $3n+2$.
Now  $2^3 \equiv 1 \mod 7$ implies $$2^{3n} \equiv 1 \mod 7$$ so that we also have $$2^{3n+1} \equiv 2 \mod 7 $$ and  $$ 2^{3n+2} \equiv 4\mod 7$$. So for any $k$ we have $2^k \equiv 1,2,4 \mod 7$

Finally observe that $2^n + 1  \equiv 0\mod 7 $ is same as $2^n   \equiv 6\mod 7 $

**Note :**   $2^n \equiv r \mod 7$ is same as the statement $7$ divides $2^n - r$